# SQL Server datatype for very large numbers

Tags: sql-server

In SQlite, if we use the datatype Real, we can store numbers such as 2E200 or 5E10, but when I use the Real datatype in SQL Server, it doesn't let me store numbers of that kind, so what is the datatype that I can use for that purpose. (of course nothing String or Char type, this is a number which means 2*10^200 or 5*10^10)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: that comment does not solve this problem as I'm not a hello world developer and I do know about datatypes, this one is something I really can't find among what I already know, so this the reason I posted the question in here

Comment: `so what is the datatype that I can use for that purpose` Do you looking for some kind of undocumented data types?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: Neither of us know how to to this, this is me asking, and at you, let's allow the ones who have encountered this problem before share their experience. You Can't, There's no such thing in the documentation, there's no way these kind of answers or comment can solve this problem, thank you though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, `float(53)` is what you're looking for:
http://technet.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms173773.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[You'll want to consult this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) to see what would work best for you.  I've used nvarchar before because I had needs for importing from many and various non-windows sources.

Comment: I want a numerical datatype for this, I don't wanna store in textual format and then cast it back, this is a huge project which was in SQlite but is migrating to SQL Server, there are way too many of these numbers in my database

Comment: The article above covers all the possible data types so you can determine what work for your purposes.  Just because you're importing numbers doesn't mean you have to start out with a numerical datatype.  Many of the datatypes can be converted into other data types.  Check out [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) and scroll half way down the page.  You can how many options for conversions you have to work with.  Using my example above, I imported into an nvarchar(max) and converted many columns/tables into decimal or numeric.